# How to get the max element from the arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, max

Pls help me!I have to get max average grade.How can we take element from arraylist and compare it with another element?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Student {

  String name;
  double averageGrade;

  public Student(String name, double averageGrade) {
    this.name = name;
    this.averageGrade = averageGrade;
  }
}

public class exam2014_07 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double max = 0;
    Student s1 = new Student("Georgi", 5.50);
    Student s2 = new Student("Ivan", 5.70);
    Student s3 = new Student("Maria", 5.80);

    ArrayList<Student> student = new ArrayList<Student>();
    student.add(s1);
    student.add(s2);
    student.add(s3);

    for (Student s : student) {
      //i need the max grade  
        if (max > s.averageGrade) {
            max = s.averageGrade;
            System.out.println("Name: " + s.name + "average grade: " + s.averageGrade);
        }   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're doing that already. Just switch the `>` and do `max < s.averageGrade`, because otherwise, `max` will never be set to anything

Comment: Set max to -1 at the beginning.

Comment: Or, as a variation on what NomadMaker commented, set initial value of `max` to [`Double.MIN_NORMAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#MIN_NORMAL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the grade of the current student is greater than the previous maximum and only print at the end of the loop after you have checked the grades of all the students.

```
Student best = null;
for (Student s : student) {
  if (max < s.averageGrade) {
      max = s.averageGrade;
      best = s;
  }   
}
System.out.println("Name: " + best.name + "average grade: " + best.averageGrade);
```

Comment: @akva No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `max` set to `0` and then `max > s.averageGrade` it will not get an results as 0 is always less than the average. If you flip the greater than to less than; then the way your for loop works will print out all the answers as each average is higher than the previously inserted value.

You can do something like this using java streams to find the max:

```
Student s = student.stream().max((m1, m2) -> m1.averageGrade.compareTo(m2.averageGrade)).orElse(null);
if (s != null)
  System.out.println("Name: " + s.name + "average grade: " + s.averageGrade);
```

and change your `averageGrade` from the primitive `double` to `Double` so we can take advantage of `compareTo`

**UPDATE**

To take advantage of java 8 and make the stream more streamlined we can do the following:

Update your student class with public getters

```
class Student {

  private String name;
  private Double averageGrade;

  public Student(String name, double averageGrade) {
    this.name = name;
    this.averageGrade = averageGrade;
  }
  
  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
  
  public Double getAverageGrade() {
    return this.averageGrade;
  }
}
```

Then we can modify the code to find max average as:

```
Optional<Student> student = students.stream()
                  .max(Comparator.comparingDouble(Student::getAverageGrade));
    
if (student.isPresent()) {
  Student s = student.get();
  System.out.println("Name: " + s.getName() + "average grade: " + s.getAverageGrade());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Stream API**, get from the `Student` object the `averageGrade` and get the max value in `OptionalDouble`

```
OptionalDouble maxOptionalDouble = student.stream().mapToDouble(stud -> stud.averageGrade).max();
if (maxOptionalDouble.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(maxOptionalDouble.getAsDouble());
}
```

---

, Or sort the students based on the `averageGrade` descending order and get the first one

```
Comparator<Student> cmp = (stud1, stud2) -> Double.valueOf(stud2.averageGrade)
                .compareTo(Double.valueOf(stud1.averageGrade));
student.sort(cmp);
Student std = student.get(0);
System.out.println("Name: " + std.name + "average grade: " + std.averageGrade);
```

Comment: Your method works but only returns the max double. It should return the student class with the max